# Camel Store message in a file component if redelivery fails in deadletter

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am having a xml file with 5 rows which am splitting on which if an exception is occuring while processing third row and redelivery also failed as part of deadletter channel.

### MyFile.xml

```
<orders>
    <order>
        <orderid>1</orderid>
    </order>
    <order>
        <orderid>2</orderid>
    </order>
    <order>
    <order> //Have not closed order intentionally to get a exception
    <order>
        <orderid>4</orderid>
    </order>
    <order>
        <orderid>5</orderid>
    </order>
</orders>
```

### MyRoute

```
    errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("log:Error Occured!!!!")
                .onExceptionOccurred(new ErrorHandlerProcessor())
                .useOriginalMessage()   
                .allowRedeliveryWhileStopping(true)
                .maximumRedeliveries(10)
                .redeliveryDelay(2000)
                .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.INFO));

            from("file:E:/camel")
                .routeId("File_Pickup_Route")
                        .split(body().tokenizeXML("order", "orders"))
                        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                        .process(new SplitProcessor())
                        .convertBodyTo(File.class)
                    .bean(MyBean.class,"saveMetaData()")
```

## ErrorHandlerProcessor

```
    public class ErrorHandlerProcessor implements Processor {

        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("\n\n Inside My Error Handler Processor()");

            try {

                Exception cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("FailedBecause", cause.getMessage());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.printstacktrace());
            }
```

### Output

```
22:47:41,094 INFO  [Error Occured!!!!] (Camel (FilePickup) thread #0 - file://E:/camel) Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: <order>
                <orderid>3</orderid>
        <order>
```

How can i save the failed stuff that is printing in the console as a separate file ?? Is that possible ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a file endpoint as the dead letter channel instead of the log endpoint, eg

```
 errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("file:errors")
```

Comment: if i do the above one it stores all the other rows after the failure has occured not only the failed row
Another one question would be can we pass it to a bean like : 
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("bean:MyBean?method?saveMetaData(${body})") 
So that i can store it into backend

Comment: Yeah you can use any Camel endpoint, or if you want to call another route, you can use direct endpoint to route to the route that then should start from direct

Comment: Thanks . But is a way there to get only failed rows now it stores row 3 (failed) and row 4 (next row) as well